# Is there a way to solve this equation arising from a weighted sum?

Tags: summation, arithmetic

If I have a weighted finite sum that is equal to a known real value $x$, and I also know the real-valued and non-negative weights $a_i$, and I have unknown but also real and non-negative elements $b_i$ :

$x = \sum a_ib_i$

is it possible to extract the value $\sum b_i$? I don't need to know the value of each element $b_i$, only their sum.

Comment: Is the sum finite - is $i\le n$? Are the weights real numbers?

Comment: Yes, the sum is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $x=3$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$.

$$3=1\cdot1+2\cdot1=1\cdot\frac12+2\cdot\frac54$$

$$1+1\neq\frac12+\frac54$$

So $\sum b_i$ is not determined by $\sum a_ib_i$.

Comment: Should the nonnegative weights $a_k$ sum to $1$ as usual for weights? Maybe your example can be adjusted to accommodate this...

Comment: Just divide the equation by $3$.